# If POTUS doesn't name a candidate to fill a SCOTUS vacancy, can the Senate fill the seat?

Tags: united-states, constitution, senate, supreme-court, political-appointments

If the President doesn't name a candidate to fill a Supreme Court vacancy, can the Senate fill the seat, anyway?

If Biden were to win re-election, the Republicans take the Senate, and a Supreme Court vacancy occurs, a Republican Senate would never confirm *any* Biden candidate, if for no other reason than pure spite.

The Constitution allows a President to *not* name a candidate. This would create an 8-member, 5-3 Republican SCOTUS, which is better than a 6-3 Republican majority. If one Republican votes with the Dems, you have a tie and no change from the status quo.

In this scenario, I don't think that the Senate *could* appoint a candidate, hold a confirmation hearing and fill the vacancy.

Answer (score 4):

> If POTUS doesn't name a candidate to fill a SCOTUS vacancy, can the Senate fill the seat, anyway?

No, the Senate cannot nominate or appoint candidates, it can only confirm (or not) Presidential nominations and appointments.

See the [US Constitution Article 2 Section 2 Clause 2](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artII-S2-C2-3-5/ALDE_00013096/):

> ... and **he [the President] shall nominate, and** *by and with the Advice and Consent of the Senate*, **shall appoint** Ambassadors, other public Ministers and Consuls, *Judges of the supreme Court*, and all other Officers of the United States ...